# Retrieve a value from hidden input field when selecting a radio button

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a table name courses

```
courses('course_id','course_name','course_desc')
```

I am using php. I have 2 rows of record in this table. And I have used a `while` loop to list the two as radio button options. I want to add a hidden input field that posts the related `course_id` to the course selected in the radio button. What I have right now is.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="courseid" value="'.$row['course_id'].'"><strong class="panel-title">'.$row['coursename'].'</strong> - '.$row['course_desc'].'<br><input type="radio" name="'.$row['coursename'].'" value="'.$row['coursename'].'"> - Choose '.$row['coursename'].'</td></tr>';
```

The related hidden input wont get selected when I select 1 of the course. How to achieve that. I hope it would be possible without use of jquery as much as possible.

Comment: why don't you put course_id into value of radio button? it will be posted then

Comment: Not the only way. You can check my answer below to get another way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put that `course_id` in value of radio field, so that you will get it posted with your form and by that `course_id` you can easily retrieve `course_name`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo '<td>'.
               '<strong class="panel-title">'.$row['coursename'].'</strong> - '.
                $row['course_desc'].'<br><input type="radio" name="'.$row['coursename'].'" value="'.$row['course_id'].'"> '.
               '- Choose '.$row['course_name']
           .'</td>';
```

**OR**

If you want to have `course_name` as well then you can change your value to something like this

```
... value="'.$row['course_id'].'-'.$row['course_name'].'" ...
```

and then you can easily break it to get `course_id` and `course_name` in PHP or JavaScript

Comment: wow does, concatinate work on the value attribute, awesome, I wanted both the values. Thank you Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

I think for a radio button to work properly, all the `name` attribute must be same. If not you will be able to select two or more radio buttons.

Comment: NO I have named both the radio buttons the same, the hidden input value should only carry the id of the related selected radio option.